# At what point are MCTS results discarded in AlphaZero Training?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, alphazero

Regarding the [AlphaZero paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01815.pdf), it is not clear to me when the Monte Carlo Tree Search (MCTS) results will be cleaned up.

I assume this has to happen at some point, since mixing results could lead to lower quality results? Imagine in the self-play the Neural Network (NN) is updated to a new version and evaluates certain patterns differently by detecting a new trick. Many iterations must follow to outperform the old best choice (visit-count). I imagine discarding old MCTS results should be done about between an episode and the next NN weight updates.

I feel that a wrong decision here could have a strong negative impact on the overall learning process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, it would not be great to keep training on games played early during the selfplay process, since they would just hurt the network playing strength.

The [AlphaZero paper](https://www.science.org/doi/10.1126/science.aar6404) ([free access](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01815.pdf)) itself does not elaborate, but it has this sneaky sentence:

> Unless
> otherwise specified, the training and search algorithm and parameters are identical to *AlphaGo Zero*

The [AlphaGo Zero paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/nature24270.pdf) ([free access](https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/10045895/1/agz_unformatted_nature.pdf)) is more helpful:

> Optimization: [...] Each mini­batch of data is sampled uniformly at random from all positions of the most recent 500,000 games of self­play.

For context, in total AlphaGoZero played 4.9 million games, so the buffer rotated about 10 times.

As another example, [KataGo](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.10565) started with a small buffer early in training and then gradually grew it:

> Samples are drawn uniformly from a growing moving window of the most recent data, with window size beginning at 250,000 samples and increasing to about 22 million by the end of the main run. See Appendix C for details.

(note that this is counting positions, not games like the AlphaZero paper)